# Absolute Positioned Span Shrinks

Tags: css

I have an unordered list of inputs and if there is an error I want the error to show to the left of the label.

Each `LI` is positioned relatively and the `span.error` is positionined absolutely. When I set the right position of the `span.error` past a certain
point the span shrinks.

Here are two js fiddle's.

The first with the position right set to 0 (this is how I want the error message to display, but to the right of the label).

http://jsfiddle.net/meander365/vmXHV/1/

And the second, with the position right set (where the span.error has shrunk)

http://jsfiddle.net/meander365/vmXHV/2/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements **collapse** by default, and won't overcome **browser's gravity** unless you define any **shifting** for it, that is, specify value for **top, right, bottom, or left** properties.

I saw two examples. Since you haven't specified any **width** for your span, it shrinks. Specify a width and you see what I mean.

In general, consider these situations for absolute positioning:

1. If you haven't specified width or height, but has specified element shifting on both directions, element stretches to fill the available space. For example, when you specify `position: absolute; left: 40px; right: 30px;` in a parent div which has `800px` width, your absolutely positioned element's width becomes 800px - 40px (left) - 30px (right) = 720px.
2. In case of a specified width or height value for the absolutely positioned element, **element shifting** doesn't stretch the element. It only **shifts** it.
3. One of the centralization techniques is absolute positioning, if you have a predefined width or height value.

   ```
   #centered 
   {
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       margin: auto;
   }
   ```

Comment: My problem is that the message in each span vary in width and so I can define a set width.  What do you think could work?

Comment: Use *floats* instead of *absolute positioning* :)

Comment: Then vote this answer up @Meander365, so others would see this answer first :)